# keyboardscrollingview issue react native

Tags: react-native

[image]

in react native i am using KeyboardAvoidingView i have tried almost each and everything to fix this issue on android on emulator it is working fine but on expo mobile device this is the issue which is i am unable to fix this is the whole code

```
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex:1}} behavior="padding" enabled={KeyboardAvoidingViewState}   keyboardVerticalOffset={100}>
```

specifically the issue is that grey area when i click on input text field

Comment: I have this issue with RN 0.60+ But with RN 0.59.10 this issue doesn't exists. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

According to the React Native documentation, `behavior` props in `KeyboardAvoidingView` may behave better when given no behavior prop at all with Android.

There are 2 ways to solve this issue

1. Remove behavior prop for Android (or you can assign different value like `height`)

```
behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : null}
```

2. Assign a value for `keyboardVerticalOffset` props

```
keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS == "ios" ? 0 : -500}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: @samair ali was this answer enough to solve your problem?